# How can we use a pandas dataframe column in string formating

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

Don't know how to ask. Want add the row values in a string using formating.like If I have a df like below:

| things | qty | place |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | Table |
| Mango | 4 | Chair |
| Coke | 3 | Floor |
| Pen | 2 | Table |

I want output like below:

| things | qty | place | string |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | 1 | Table | 1 Apple on the Table |
| Mango | 4 | Chair | 4 Mango on the Chair |
| Coke | 3 | Floor | 3 Coke on the Floor |
| Pen | 2 | Table | 2 Pen on the Table |

I'm using `df['string'] = f'{df['qty']} {df['things']} on the {df['place']}'` but not getting the exact.

Answer (score 1):

Just use :-

```
df['string']=df['qty'].astype(str)+' '+df['things']+' on the '+df['place']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the dataframe into a dictionary.
2. Add the new data column to the dictionary in the same format.
3. Convert the dictionary back to a dataframe

   data_dict = df.to_dict()

   data_dict["string"] = ["1 Apple on the Table"......]

   pd.Dataframe.from_dict(data_dict)

Here's an article which might be of help: https://re-thought.com/how-to-add-new-columns-in-a-dataframe-in-pandas/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html#pandas-series-str-cat) here.

```py
df["qty"].astype(str).str.cat(
    [df["things"], ("on the " + df["place"])], sep=" "
)

0    1 Apple on the Table
1    4 Mango on the Chair
2     3 Coke on the Floor
3      2 Pen on the Table
Name: qty, dtype: object
```

If you want to use `f-string` then you can use `df.apply` over axis 1(but this approach is slow and should be used as last resort).

```py
df.apply(lambda x: f'{x.qty} {x.things} on the {x.place}', axis=1)
```